# Tag duplicate: wol -> wake-on-lan

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Can we have [wol](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wol) made a synonym of [wake-on-lan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wake-on-lan) please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonym created by [studiohack ♦](https://superuser.com/users/6574/studiohack) about two hours ago.

Comment: thanks @random, I saw nhinkle's request on MSO and carried it out, but then got called away before the question was migrated here to MSU.